# Mysql - Drop table if exists not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I try to use the following code to empty a database (delete all tables) :

```
SELECT concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ','`',table_schema,'`','.','`',table_name,'`',';') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DB';
```

I am getting an output of the commands, but nothing happens to the database. If I take an individual command from the output, and run it in the console, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As you know, `SELECT` only returns the result of a query. It doesn't know you actually intend to execute the result of that query. (In most cases, that would make no sense.) You can use prepared statements to do what you want (untested):

```
SET @s:='';
SELECT @s:=concat(@s, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ','`',table_schema,'`','.','`',table_name,'`',';') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DB';   
PREPARE stm FROM @s;
EXECUTE stm;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you're using SELECT statement, Simply try this query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;
```

Comment: Your answer (`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name`) would `DROP` a table that is literally named `table_name`. The question is how to `DROP` a table whose name is obtained from the result of a `SELECT` query.